# How can I run evolutions step by step?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am learning Play 2.0 framework and I noticed I had some problems with one of the evolutions. I had some time until I could find the problem by trial/error...

But I was wondering if there is some way to run evolutions step by step, so I can check where is the problematic evolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The best way to prevent these issues is to test the evolution manually in a test DB (created only for this purpose) when creating the evolution, so you can verify each command individually.

Given that you already have the error, you could do that. The alternative is to comment lines in the evolution file and re-apply the "new" evolution, but that could (potentially) break your DB and depending on the amount of data you have in there for testing purposes, it may be a bad option.